# My if/else conditions are not displaying as they should

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript and I went off script from my course to just play around with what knowledge I currently have attained.

As a challenge to see if I understood Control Flow and Functions parameters, I decided to make a Container Dock log. The idea is to log containers based on their arrival and docked time:

- New containers are those that have docked for less than 30 minutes.
- Old containers are those that docked for at least 30 minutes.

Based on that information, I made the following code:

```js
// Containers type: Old and New based on 30min arrivals.

const containerDocked = (container,arrivalTime) => {
  newContainer = arrivalTime < 30;
  oldContainer = arrivalTime >= 30;
  if (newContainer) {
    console.log('New Container: ' + container + ' just arrived ' + arrivalTime + 'min ago.' );
  } 
    else if (oldContainer) {
      console.log('Docked Container: ' + container + ' has been docked for ' + arrivalTime + 'min.');
    }
    else if(container === false && arrivalTime === true) {
      console.log('A container that arrived '+ arrivalTime + 'mins ago, has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else if(container === true && arrivalTime === false) {
      console.log('Container: ' + container + 'has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Container has not been logged!!!!');
    }
};

containerDocked('John', 24);
containerDocked('Elizabeth', 57);
containerDocked('Harry', 30);
containerDocked('Mike');
```

It does seem to work, but as you can see "Mike" does not log, with on my if/else rules. Can you point me as to what I did wrong?

Comment: In `containerDocked('Mike');`,  `arrivalTime` is undefined, and undefined > or < 30 will always return false

Comment: Which `if/else` block do you expect that should be called?

Comment: You are testing true/false on values that can be undefined. That wont work for you case.

Comment: While the posted answers will/might work, they probably don't refelct what you actually want to test. If `container === true && arrivalTime === false` should test that you called the function with just one argument, then using a regular (not arrow) function and  `arguments.length` to how many arguments are passt might be a better and more verbose solution. How the last two `else if` should look like, depends one what exactly you want to test.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fix

Problem with `container === true` and `arrivalTime === true`

```js
// Containers type: Old and New based on 30min arrivals.

const containerDocked = (container,arrivalTime) => {
  newContainer = arrivalTime < 30;
  oldContainer = arrivalTime >= 30;
  if (newContainer) {
    console.log('New Container: ' + container + ' just arrived ' + arrivalTime + 'min ago.' );
  } 
    else if (oldContainer) {
      console.log('Docked Container: ' + container + ' has been docked for ' + arrivalTime + 'min.');
    }
    else if(!container && arrivalTime) {
      console.log('A container that arrived '+ arrivalTime + 'mins ago, has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else if(container && !arrivalTime) {
      console.log('Container: ' + container + 'has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Container has not been logged!!!!');
    }
};

containerDocked('John', 24);
containerDocked('Elizabeth', 57);
containerDocked('Harry', 30);
containerDocked('Mike');
```

Comment: @MarioMurrent depends one what exactly should be tested. It most likely will work, but because it is not clear out of the question what the OP wants to test it not necessarily the correct check. (e.g. if the the OP wants to test if one or tho arguments are passed, then this would be the wrong test)

Comment: @t.niese - Can you elaborate on when the case will fail?

Comment: @nikhilagw I didn't say it will fail. I just said that it is not clear based in the OPs question if the given code does the _"correct"_ checks. So if `container === true && arrivalTime === false`  should only be entered if `containerDocked`  is called with one argument, then your solution will fail, because `container && !arrivalTime` would also be called for `containerDocked('Mike', undefined)`, but as I saied it is not clear if that should be the case.

Comment: @t.niese - Okay. That is also a way to approach the problem. However, based on the console.log, as per my understanding the OP wanted the 5 if/else checks to work as per the implementation where it should go inside the condition if falsy value is passed for !argument.   Let us leave this to OP to decide the requirement. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check wether arrivalTime is null or not in the else if statement.

```js
// Containers type: Old and New based on 30min arrivals.

const containerDocked = (container,arrivalTime) => {
  newContainer = arrivalTime < 30;
  oldContainer = arrivalTime >= 30;
  if (newContainer) {
    console.log('New Container: ' + container + ' just arrived ' + arrivalTime + 'min ago.' );
  } 
    else if (oldContainer) {
      console.log('Docked Container: ' + container + ' has been docked for ' + arrivalTime + 'min.');
    }
    else if(container === false && arrivalTime === true) {
      console.log('A container that arrived '+ arrivalTime + 'mins ago, has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else if(container !=null && !arrivalTime) {
      console.log('Container: ' + container + ' has not been logged!!!');
    }
    else {
      console.log('Container has not been logged!!!!');
    }
};

containerDocked('John', 24);
containerDocked('Elizabeth', 57);
containerDocked('Harry', 30);
containerDocked('Mike');
```

Comment: In the case of `containerDocked('Mike');`, the `arrivalTime` is `undefined` and not `null`.

Comment: agreed, let me edit that. Although this will also work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mike dosen't log because you haven't specified the `arrivalTime` when calling `containerDocked`. This means that `arrivalTime` is `undefined` and all of those conditions you have return `false`, and the `else` block is executed.

Note that `arrivalTime === false` is `false`.

Comment: If `arrivalTime` is `undefined` then both `arrivalTime === false` and `arrivalTime == false` are `false`.